# How to make a Q-Q Plot with a Student-t distribution

Tags: matlab, distribution

Working in Matlab...

I have a long vector of data `vec` that I want to make a Q-Q plot of against a Student-t distribution for various values of t. I know `qqplot(vec)` produces a plot against a normal distribution. I know from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/qqplot.html) that I can use other distributions by inserting them as a second parameter `qqplot(vec,dis)`.

I can make other distributions with `makedist` (see mathworks.com/help/stats/makedist.html) but Student-t isn't an option there that I can see. There are the functions `tpdf`, `tcdf` etc. about Student-t (see http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/students-t-distribution-1.html) but how do I use them to make a distribution item to use in the Q-Q plot? Or is there another technique to get the plot I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Matlab in about a decade, so I can't give specific syntax.  That said, if `vec` has length `n` you should be able to create a vector of t-values corresponding to quantiles `i / (n+1)` for `i=1,...,n` using [`tinv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tinv.html).  Then do a `qqplot` of `vec` vs. the t-vector.